# Can not get kendo element from view in angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui

I am trying to get kendo datepicker element from my view in Angular. It's how I am trying to achieve this

```
              var element = angular.element("#finishDate");
```

and my html code

```
                <input id="startDate" kendo-date-picker
                   data-ng-model="startDate"
                   data-k-options="dataPickerOptions"
                   data-ng-change="dateChange()"
                   style="width: 60%;"
                   placeholder="From" />
```

I find out that this object for which I am looking for is hidden inside some strange propertis which every single time is diffrent. I need this to set date manually from code side.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried var datePicker = $("#startDate").data("kendoDatePicker") ?

Comment: Your solution is working well but finally I bind it to $scope
`kendo-drop-down-list="timePeriodDropDownList"`